# Where is the backend of Jetbrains Gateway being installed?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-gateway

I'm at a point where the IDE won't start anymore at all and I'd like to find the IDE backend inside my WSL Ubuntu and delete it manually.

**Where does Jetbrains Gateway install the backend on Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-a.html#use_idea):

In case of backend previously installed by JetBrains Gateway, the default path is `/home/your_system_user/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/`